# UserManager.CreateAsync does NOT create a new user profile inside my seeding class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

For some reason, the 'UserManager' of 'Identity' does not store a new user when using inside my seeding class. Everything else in the seeding class works fine as expected, it is just that 'CreateAsync' method issue. Here is the code:

```
public class WorldContextSeedData
{
    private WorldContext _context;
    private UserManager<WorldUser> _userManager;

    public WorldContextSeedData(WorldContext context, UserManager<WorldUser> userManager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task EnsureSeedData()
    {
        if (await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("lucas@test.com") == null)
        {
            //add user
            var newUser = new WorldUser
            {
                UserName = "Lucas",
                Email = "lucas@test.com"
            };

            await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, "MyP@ssword!");
        }

        if (!_context.Trips.Any())
        {
            //Add new Data
            var usTrip = new Trip()
            {
                Name = "US Trip",
                CreatedBy = "Lucas",
                Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
                Stops = new List<Stop>()
                {
                    new Stop { Name= "Atlanta, GA", Order = 0},
                    new Stop { Name= "NYC, NY", Order = 1},
                    new Stop { Name= "Tempe, AZ", Order = 2}
                }
            };

            var worldTrip = new Trip()
            {
                Name = "World Trip",
                CreatedBy = "Lucas",
                Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
                Stops = new List<Stop>()
                {
                    new Stop { Name= "Poland", Order = 0},
                    new Stop { Name= "France", Order = 1},
                    new Stop { Name= "Germany", Order = 2}
                }
            };

            _context.Trips.Add(usTrip);
            _context.Stops.AddRange(usTrip.Stops);

            _context.Trips.Add(worldTrip);
            _context.Stops.AddRange(worldTrip.Stops);

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try checking the result: "IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, "MyP@ssword!");"

Comment: Perfect Steve, thanks a lot, how could I omit that debug option, the result came with the password not containing a digit, it is all good now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Steve's great comment tip, I was able to verify that the password was too weak. Once I made the password stronger (digit was required), the issue was resolved.

Here, I have introduced a variable that would contain returned result of creating a new user:

```
IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, newUserPassword);
```

Comment: In vs2019 no error and no return result, just doesn't seem to do anything. A breakpoint on any code after doesn't get hit :(

Comment: @djack109 , there is error thrown. Eventually the error is object disposed. Try ot wrap it with try{ code target } catch (Exception e) { code breakpoint to }

Comment: mine was wrapped in a try/catch but I had the same issue as I was trying to set the password as the username of the identity user and it was happy and didn't throw an exception but was not saving the user to the DB

Answer (score 1):

You can Use

```
    IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, "MyP@ssword!");
```

to see what is the problem in result. 
IdentityResult contains bool Succeeded for determine how the create going on. and contains Errors Property to show you what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

add these line of codes to IdentityHostingStartup.cs:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(x => {
x.Password.RequireDigit = false;
x.Password.RequiredLength = 2;
x.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
x.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
x.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
x.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
x.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
x.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
x.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
});
```